# Reading live output from telnet connection in python

Tags: python, c++, arduino, telnet, telnetlib

I have an Arduino set up as a server. In Terminal (I use a Mac), one can connect to it, see the output, and close the connection as follows:

```
> telnet HOST
Trying 192.168.0.101...
Connected to HOST.
Escape character is '^]'.
0 , 25486 , 0.00 :
1 , 25754 , 0.00 :
2 , 26054 , 0.00 :
3 , 26320 , 0.00 :
4 , 26642 , 0.00 :
5 , 26912 , 0.00 :
6 , 27187 , 0.00 :
7 , 27452 , 0.00 :
8 , 27774 , 0.00 :
0 , 28068 , 2.72 :
1 , 28389 , 2.72 :
2 , 28695 , 2.72 :
3 , 29002 , 2.72 :
4 , 29272 , 2.72 :
5 , 29537 , 2.72 :
6 , 29806 , 2.72 :
7 , 30112 , 2.72 :
8 , 30389 , 2.72 :
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

The data currently streams at around 5 lines per second, without delay. I then tried to recreate this connection in a Python script using `telnetlib`.

```
import telnetlib
import time

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.set_debuglevel(1)

while True:
    tn_read = tn.read_very_eager()
    time.sleep(1)
    print repr(tn_read)
```

This script only returns empty strings. I read about there being a timing issue, so I included a manual delay. I have also tried `tn.read_until(':')` to no avail.

My resulting questions:

1. Is there any way to pull one line at a time, assuming the incoming stream is continuous and effectively never-ending?
2. How is this implemented in Python?

Thank you.

EDIT: 
I've included the void loop for the Arduino code.

```
void loop(void){
    // Handle any multicast DNS requests
    mdns.update();

    // Handle a connected client.
    Adafruit_CC3000_ClientRef client = senseServer.available();
    if (client) {
        Serial.println("Connected");
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i ++){ //sets number of channels
        client.print(i);
        client.print(" , ");  
        stamp = millis();  
        client.print(stamp);
        client.print(" , ");
        client.print(R2);
        client.println(" :");
        delay(10);
    }
    e = e + 1;
    R2 = pow(2.718,e);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the code for the server on the arduino look like?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code.

Comment: Telnet is normally served on port 23, can you confirm that your server is using port 23 Look for a line like `Adafruit_CC3000_Server senseServer(PORT);`

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the server is using port 23. I've been able to receive some data using my code from above if I add the line `tn.write(some_string)` at the beginning of the while loop. So, it seems like the client has to write a certain number of bytes to receive data?

Answer (score 1):

Can you work at a lower level, using the [`socket` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html)?

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.0.101", 23))

while True:
    data = str(s.recv(1024),encoding='utf-8')
    print(data)
```

Why this should work: It seems that your server is not a full telnet server (requiring a login etc) but a socket that waits for a connection, and then returns data.

Since the server is just a socket, you can connect to it with a simple socket, which is what the above does.  I tested this in two ways. First with the Star wars telnet server at `towel.blinkenlights.nl`, and secondly with a simple python server that waits for a connection and then returns a line of text every second (to simulate your server).

Comment: I tried that code and it just hangs; it doesn't print empty strings or anything.